# SQL Compare Hourly Total Orders and Remove Current Stock Possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Not sure if this can be done using sql alone but I'd rather ask then add another step to a process.

so say for example I have a set of dummy orders

```
+----------+-------------+----------+----------+-----------------+-----+
| Supplier | Destination | Req_Time | Prd_Code | Prd_Description | Qty |
+----------+-------------+----------+----------+-----------------+-----+
| A        | B           | 01:00    |        1 | Chair           | 100 |
| A        | B           | 01:00    |        2 | Desk            |  50 |
| A        | B           | 01:00    |        3 | Phone           |  20 |
| A        | B           | 05:00    |        1 | Chair           | 200 |
| A        | B           | 05:00    |        2 | Desk            |  20 |
+----------+-------------+----------+----------+-----------------+-----+
```

And a current stock list

```
+----------+----------+----------+-------+
| Supplier | Prd_Code | Prd_Desc | Stock |
+----------+----------+----------+-------+
| A        |        1 | Chair    |   150 |
| A        |        2 | Desk     |    40 |
| A        |        3 | Phone    |   100 |
+----------+----------+----------+-------+
```

is there a way I can produce a Stored Procedure (SQL 2008 -Compatible) that can subtract what I do have in stock and leave me with what I require like so

```
+----------+-------------+----------+----------+-----------------+-----+
| Supplier | Destination | Req_Time | Prd_Code | Prd_Description | Qty |
+----------+-------------+----------+----------+-----------------+-----+
| A        | B           | 01:00    |        2 | Desk            |  10 |
| A        | B           | 05:00    |        1 | Chair           | 150 |
| A        | B           | 05:00    |        2 | Desk            |  20 |
+----------+-------------+----------+----------+-----------------+-----+
```

I'd like to show you what I have attempted but in this case I wouldn't know where to start.

P.S
Have to thank this site for formatting the tables for me very easily
https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Will Appreciate any insight and any examples even more :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have SQL Server to hand and SQLFiddle isn't playing nicely with me lately, so this is untested, but the logic should work...

```
WITH
    stock_changes
AS
(
    SELECT Supplier, Destination, Req_Time, Prd_Code, Prd_Description, -Qty AS Qty FROM orders
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Supplier, NULL, '00:00', Prd_Code, Prd_Desc, Stock FROM stock
),
    stock_post_order
AS
(
    SELECT
        *,
        SUM(Qty) OVER (PARTITION BY Supplier, Prd_Code
                           ORDER BY Req_Time
                               ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                      )
                         AS new_qty
   FROM
       stock_changes
)
SELECT
    *,
    CASE WHEN new_qty > qty THEN new_qty ELSE qty END   AS order_shortfall
FROM
    stock_post_order
WHERE
    new_qty < 0
```

First invert your order quantities to be negative, so they are the amount the stock levels are going to change by.

Next, union your stock levels to the orders, with a required time of 0 *(to make it a bit like an order that delivers stock rather than takes stock, and come before all your other orders)*.

Next, work out what the total remaining quantity of a product is after an order; by summing up all the preceding rows (in time order) for that product.  *(Giving `Stock - Order1 - Order2, etc, etc`)*

Then select the rows where the new stock level has gone negative.

Comment: Very nice answer and yes the logic looks good, i'll adapt to my scenario and let you know the result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
SELECT
    S.Prd_Code
    ,S.Stock - Ord.OrderedQty AS RemainingStock
FROM Stock S
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        Prd_Code
        , SUM(Qty) OrderedQty 
    FROM Orders 
    GROUP BY Prd_Code
) Ord
```

Comment: That won't give two rows at two times for the shortfall of desks.  The OP essentially wants to know how much Each Order is short by, not just Each Product.  *(Had 40 desks, reduce by 50 at '01:00', so short by 10, then reduce by 20 at '05:00' so short by 20 for that order.)*

Comment: @MatBailie: Thanks! I couldn't figure that out.