# SQL Server 2008 version of OVER(... Rows Unbounded Preceding)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, window-functions

Looking for help in converting this to SQL Server 2008 friendly as I just can't work it out. I've tried cross applies and inner joins (not saying I did them right) to no avail... Any suggestions?

What this essentially does is have a table of stock and a table of orders.
and combine the two to show me what to pick once the stock is taken away (see my previous question for more details [More Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872845/sql-compare-hourly-total-orders-and-remove-current-stock-possible))

```
WITH ADVPICK
     AS (SELECT 'A'                  AS PlaceA,
                placeb,
                CASE
                  WHEN picktime = '00:00' THEN '07:00'
                  ELSE ISNULL(picktime, '12:00')
                END                  AS picktime,
                Cast(product AS INT) AS product,
                prd_description,
                -qty                 AS Qty
         FROM   t_pick_orders
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'A'               AS PlaceA,
                placeb,
                '0',
                Cast(code AS INT) AS product,
                NULL,
                stock
         FROM   t_pick_stock),
     STOCK_POST_ORDER
     AS (SELECT *,
                Sum(qty)
                  OVER (
                    PARTITION BY placeb, product
                    ORDER BY picktime ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) AS new_qty
         FROM   ADVPICK)
SELECT *,
       CASE
         WHEN new_qty > qty THEN new_qty
         ELSE qty
       END AS order_shortfall
FROM   STOCK_POST_ORDER
WHERE  new_qty < 0
ORDER  BY placeb,
          picktime,
          product
```

Now the whole sum over partition by order by is SQL Server 2012+ however I have two servers that run on 2008 and so need it converted...

Expected Results:

```
+--------+--------+----------+---------+-----------+-------+---------+-----------------+
| PlaceA | PlaceB | Picktime | product | Prd_Descr |  qty  | new_qty | order_shortfall |
+--------+--------+----------+---------+-----------+-------+---------+-----------------+
| BW     | AMES   | 16:00    |    1356 | Product A | -1330 |     -17 |             -17 |
| BW     | AMES   | 16:00    |      17 | Product B |   -48 |     -42 |             -42 |
| BW     | AMES   | 17:00    |    1356 | Product A |  -840 |    -857 |            -840 |
| BW     | AMES   | 18:00    |    1356 | Product A |  -770 |   -1627 |            -770 |
| BW     | AMES   | 18:00    |      17 | Product B |  -528 |    -570 |            -528 |
| BW     | AMES   | 19:00    |    1356 | Product A |  -700 |   -2327 |            -700 |
| BW     | AMES   | 20:00    |    1356 | Product A |  -910 |   -3237 |            -910 |
| BW     | AMES   | 20:00    |    8009 | Product C |  -192 |     -52 |             -52 |
| BW     | AMES   | 20:00    |     897 | Product D |   -90 |     -10 |             -10 |
+--------+--------+----------+---------+-----------+-------+---------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a description of what the code does would help.

Comment: please read question, all of that is supplied in the more details link

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 is no longer supported. Perhaps you should consider upgrading the servers?

Comment: I agree they should however that is out of my control

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, can you provide any link for proof of *No longer support for 2008 R2*

Comment: @Vikrant do I have to? [End-of-life announcements](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/end-of-mainstream-support-for-sql-server-2008-and-sql-server-2008-r2/), online docs no longer have any version prior to 2012, not even [CREATE TABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx)

Comment: Mainstream support for SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3 [ended two years ago](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=sql%20server%202008%20r2). This means, no docs, no fixes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One straight-forward way to do it is to use a correlated sub-query in `CROSS APPLY`.

If your table is more or less large, then your next question would be how to make it fast. Index on `PlaceB, Product, PickTime INCLUDE (Qty)` should help. But, if your table is really large, cursor would be better.

```
WITH
ADVPICK
AS
(
    SELECT 'A' as PlaceA,PlaceB, case when PickTime = '00:00' then '07:00' else isnull(picktime,'12:00') end as picktime, cast(Product as int) as product, Prd_Description, -Qty AS Qty FROM t_pick_orders
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A' as PlaceA,PlaceB, '0', cast(Code as int) as product, NULL, Stock FROM t_pick_stock
)
,stock_post_order
AS
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        ADVPICK AS Main
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT SUM(Sub.Qty) AS new_qty
            FROM ADVPICK AS Sub
            WHERE
                Sub.PlaceB = Main.PlaceB
                AND Sub.Product = Main.Product
                AND T.PickTime <= Main.PickTime
        ) AS A
)
SELECT
    *,
    CASE WHEN new_qty > qty THEN new_qty ELSE qty END AS order_shortfall
FROM
    stock_post_order
WHERE
    new_qty < 0
ORDER BY PlaceB, picktime, product;
```

Oh, and if `(PlaceB, Product, PickTime)` is not unique, you'll get somewhat different results to original query with `SUM() OVER`. If you need exactly same results, you need to use some extra column (like `ID`) to resolve the ties.

Comment: Thank you Vladimir, I tried this approach before and it resulted in a blank result but then as you said Picktime is not unique (i'll post a snippet of the result table)

Comment: Found the cause of the blank result was a mistype, Answer works perfectly thank you.

Comment: @LRiley, actually, what matters is if the combination of `(PlaceB, Product, PickTime)` is unique. I'm glad it worked for you.